# jq compare 2 json files and delete duplicate objects by key value

Tags: json, linux, unix, command-line, jq

I have 2 json files that I wish to compare with each other and end up with a file that has just the unique objects from the second file. A unique object is not determined by the full object but rather by the value of one key within it called `Car ID`. Below are a sample of the json files to explain this better:

file1.json:

```
{
"User Data": [
{"First Name": "Tony", "Last Name": "Evans", "DOB": "1987-02-01", "Car ID": "UJ928JD9"},
{"First Name": "John", "Last Name": "Smith", "DOB": "1972-11-27", "Car ID": "UJ235UW8"},
{"First Name": "Kirsty", "Last Name": "Morgan", "DOB": "1991-06-08", "Car ID": "UJ424KL2"},
...
]
}
```

file2.json

```
{
"User Data": [
{"First Name": "Harry", "Last Name": "Jones", "DOB": "1983-03-09", "Car ID": "UJ928JD9"},
{"First Name": "Jeremy", "Last Name": "Blake", "DOB": "1965-09-21", "Car ID": "UJ345IE2"},
{"First Name": "Jason", "Last Name": "Roberts", "DOB": "1972-10-18", "Car ID": "UJ424KL2"},
...
]
}
```

In the sample above, the Car ID is the same for 2 lines so only the second object from the second file should remain, as so:

```
{
    "User Data": [
    {"First Name": "Jeremy", "Last Name": "Blake", "DOB": "1965-09-21", "Car ID": "UJ345IE2"}
    ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read in both files as variables using `--argfile`, then `map` both to just their `Car ID`, then subtract the first array from the second resulting in an array of `Car ID`s you want to keep, and finally use the keys to `select` the right elements from the second input file.

```
jq -n \
  --argfile file1 file1.json \
  --argfile file2 file2.json \
  '
    # Take both input files and create an array $ids with all
    # Car IDs from the second file that are not part of the first one
    [ $file1, $file2 ]
    | map(.["User Data"] | map(.["Car ID"]))
    | (.[1] - .[0]) as $ids
    
    # Take the second input file and select only those entries
    # whose Car ID is part of the previously stored array of Car IDs
    | $file2
    | .["User Data"] |= map(select(.["Car ID"] == $ids[]))
  '
```

Comment: Is it more efficient to use `select(.["Car ID"] | IN($ids[]))` ?

Comment: Not only is it more efficient, it is more robust (i.e., less dependent on assumptions that might be violated).